# lambda invoke local with layers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am trying to test my lambda layers locally by cheating with the layer cache option but cannot make it work
I use sam cdk and python3

in my api/lambda_layers/common I have a file named common.py container a simple function that I like to share accross my lambda

```
sam local invoke  createLocations --event api/events/create_location_event.json -t cdk/cdk.out/LocationsAPI.template.json --layer-cache-basedir  api/lambda_layers/common --force-image-build --docker-network lambda-local
```

Although in my app.py I have imported 'common', I am getting

````
commonlayer8CAC0AFA is a local Layer in the template
Building image........................
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'common'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}```

is there any other solution than --layer-cache-basedir ?
````

Answer (score 0):

Try `--docker-volume-basedir` option in sam command.

Comment: `--docker-volume-basedir  api/lambda_layers/common` same error